# Set properties from another class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties

I am having a problem trying to set properties which will be set by another class, here are two properties which will be used to populate a table:

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *friendsNames;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *friendsIDs;
@end
```

In this class (inherit from `NSObject`) I am setting them using this method:

```
@implementation MyFacebooDelegate

-(void)getFriends:(NSArray *)names {
    NSMutableArray *friendsNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *friendsIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *friend = [names objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *name = [friend objectForKey:@"name"];
        [friendsIDs addObject:[friend objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [friendsNames addObject:name];
    }

    if(tableController == nil)
        tableController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

    [tableController setFriendsIDs:friendsIDs];
    [tableController setFriendsNames:friendsNames];
    NSLog(@"%@", [tableController friendsNames]); 

    [friendsNames release];
    [friendsIDs release];
}
```

The names all print on the console (`NSLog(@"%@", [tableController friendsNames])`) but not in the TableViewController class.

If I try to print the content of two arrays in the `viewDidLoad` of the TableViewController class then it will be null, also the arrays are set before the table appears on the screen.

Comment: Where does `tableController` get pushed or presented?

Comment: it get pushed by pressing a button from another UIViewControler class

Comment: If it continues to cause you problems I would simple take the for loop (for getFriends method) and insert it into you TableViewController class. It's not a lot of code and would be cleaner than trying to abstract into a new class.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is: is the one that gets pushed the same object that you `alloc` and `init` here or  a different instance of a `TableViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong way... you should set `MyFaceboo` `delegate` as `UITableViewController`'s  `tableView`'s datasource and implement `UITableViewDataSourceProtocol`

Comment: no you don't get it ,,, the method role is to parse the results and then pass it to the UITableViewController by setting the two arrays

Comment: If you insist, try to cause reload event TableViewController from FacebooDelegate,[[tableController] tableView] reloadData]; although not sure that it will work. Proper way to do this would be delegate paradigm, in way to invoke FacebookDelegate from TableViewController and implement method which FacebookDelegate will invoke when arrays are ready

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would use value of `friendNames` & `friendIds` from with in `UITableViewController` (that would implement `UITableViewDataSource` .. I do not see it in your snippet so mentioning it)

Can you re-write your properties as (assuming you are using ARC):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *friendsNames;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *friendsIDs;
```

and use this syntax:

```
tableController.friendNames = friendNames;
tableController.friendIDs = frinedIDs
```

and make sure that you do show the `tableController` that you are creating here and not some other (it is not clear from your snippet how you are showing/pushing this `tableController` so mentioning it)

Comment: In my TableViewController class I implement the UITableView delegate and datasource, second thing I don't use ARC here

Comment: @MohamMadSalah It's easy enough to convert to ARC though. Did you ever find a solution to this?